# Where do Custom Fields for Contributions appear?

Tags: custom-fields, contributions

I have created a Set of Custom Fields called "Tracking" to be used for any Contributions.  The Custom Fields created in this set are called "Category" and "Job".
[image]

However, I can't see these fields anywhere I have looked?  Where should they appear?

Answer (score 3):

They should appear at the bottom of your contribution form, like so:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

They should be displayed if you view or edit a contribution which can be done in various ways. For example pull up a contact who has a contribution, go to the tab "contributions" and click on view for a contribution.

Be aware that if you want to be able to find the contributions via a search you should make the fields searchable.